# Probability of expected value of independent events

Tags: probability

> Four independent astronomers are being sent into space with the
>   objective of finding planet Ceres. The first astronomer has 40% chance
>   of finding the planet, the second has 50% chance, the third 60% chance
>   and the fourth has 80% chance. Calculated the expected value of a random variable $Z$ that is equal to the number of astronauts that found the planet.

I've tried calculating the probability of each value of the random variable by counting the possible outcomes that give such value and if more than one add them.

I ended up with something like $P(Z=1)=\frac{41}{125}$, $P(Z=2)=\frac{19}{50}$, $P(Z=3)=\frac{41}{125}$, $P(Z=4)=\frac{12}{125}$,$P(Z=0)=\frac{3}{125}$

And I proceeded on calculating the probability from there onwards. However, I tried to add the probabilities up just to confirm I'm not wrong and they don't add up to $1$. Does that mean something is wrong?

Comment: I believe something is wrong.  Your value for $P(Z=0)$ appears to be correct though.  Take a look at your value for $P(Z=4)$. That one should be easy to calculate.

Comment: Yes, they should add up to 1. Your value for $P(Z=1)$ is wrong for sure. I did not check others, though.

Comment: After your edits, you need to check your value for $P(Z=1)$

Comment: "Calculating the probability of each value of the random variable" Z is not needed to compute the mean of Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just had a typo somewhere, but $P(Z=1)$ should be $(.4*.5*.4*.2)+(.6*.5*.4*.2)+(.6*.5*.6*.2)+(.6*.5*.4*.8)$

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We have $Z=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$ where $X_1\sim\mathrm{Ber}(2/5)$, $X_2\sim\mathrm{Ber}(1/2)$, $X_3\sim\mathrm{Ber}(3/5)$, and $X_4\sim\mathrm{Ber}(4/5)$. Hence

$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[Z] &= \mathbb E[X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4]\\ 
&= \mathbb E[X_1] + \mathbb E[X_2] + \mathbb E[X_3] + \mathbb E[X_4]\\
&= 2/5 + 1/2 + 3/5 + 4/5\\
&= 23/10. \end{align*}$

Comment: can you please explain this a bit. I had taken a basic probability course which covered various probability distributions.